# addObject: to NSMutableArray and sending to TableView

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, tableview

Xcode 4.2
iPhone Project

I am trying to create a tableView that's populated from an NSMutableArray. Currently when I run the simulator the tableView in question shows 5 rows (this is correct) but all rows have the same string (this obviously is not correct). The string being shown is from the LAST object defined in my NSMutableArray. Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

codes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
TableList *listItem = [[TableList alloc] init];

[listItem setCodeTitle:@"Test Name 1"];
[listItem setCodeNumber:@"101"];
[listItem setCodeDescription:@"This is the description for 101."];
[codes addObject:listItem];

[listItem setCodeTitle:@"Test Name 2"];
[listItem setCodeNumber:@"102"];
[listItem setCodeDescription:@"This is the description for 102."];
[codes addObject:listItem];

[listItem setCodeTitle:@"Test Name 3"];
[listItem setCodeNumber:@"103"];
[listItem setCodeDescription:@"This is the description for 103."];
[codes addObject:listItem];

[listItem setCodeTitle:@"Test Name 4"];
[listItem setCodeNumber:@"104"];
[listItem setCodeDescription:@"This is the description for 104."];
[codes addObject:listItem];

[listItem setCodeTitle:@"Test Name 5"];
[listItem setCodeNumber:@"105"];
[listItem setCodeDescription:@"This is the description for 105."];
[codes addObject:listItem];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [codes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CodeCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
TableList *current = [codes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [current codeTitle];

return cell;
}
```

I hope this is painfully obvious to anyone with more experience than me... I have very little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're storing the exact same object 5 times into your array. You seem to be under the misapprehension that `-addObject:` will copy the object it's handed, but it won't. The simple fix is to change your `-addObject:` lines to say

```
[codes addObject:[[listItem copy] autorelease]];
```

This is, of course, assuming your `TableList` class conforms to `<NSCopying>`. If it doesn't, you'll probably want to do so. If you're unwilling to support copying in that class, then you'll have to create a new `TableList` object each time.

Also, unless you're using ARC, you're leaking your `TableList` object.

---

In order to support `-copy`, you must conform to `<NSCopying>`, which is a protocol that declares the method `-copyWithZone:` (though the zone argument is a historical curiosity that should be ignored). To do this, modify your `@interface` line to look like

```
@interface TableList : NSObject <NSCopying>
```

and then implement the method `-copyWithZone:`

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    // If our superclass conformed to <NSCopying> we'd call [super copy]
    // But it doesn't, so alloc/init a new instance
    TableList *newObj = [[TableList alloc] init];
    newObj.codeTitle = self.codeTitle;
    newObj.codeNumber = self.codeNumber;
    newObj.codeDescription = self.codeDescription;
    return newObj;
}
```

This is just a sample implementation. It assumes that those 3 properties are the only values on the object, and that simply assigning to the property is appropriate. If you have internal ivars that need to be copied over, you can get ivar access by using something like

```
newObj->ivar = copyIvar(self->ivar); // self->ivar is the same as just plain ivar
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using ARC, so no need to release that class. Also because I am using ARC, I won't be able to use autorelease in my code. I have just tried replacing the addObject lines with:
    [codes addObject:[listItem copy]];
I receive a SIGABRT when the tableView tries to load.

Perhaps this is because my class does not support copying?

Comment: @Paul: Under ARC you can just omit the `autorelease`. What line is the SIGABRT on? If your `TableList` doesn't conform to `<NSCopying>` then the call to `-copy` will throw an exception.

Comment: My class TableList was created as a subclass of NSObject, I believe this allows it to use copy.

Comment: SIGABRT on this first addObject line '[codes addObject:[listItem copy]];'

Comment: I have successfully displayed the array inside the TableView by creating an object for each cell. ( listItem0, listItem1, listItem2... ). But that seems unnecessary and inefficient. Is there a way to reuse the same object to populate my NSMutableArray?

Comment: @Paul: `NSObject` implements `-copy`, but it's [explicitly documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/copy) that if the object doesn't conform to `<NSCopying>` (e.g. doesn't implement `-copyWithZone:`) then `-copy` will throw an exception. That's what's happening.

Comment: @Paul: As for being "inefficient", your suggestion doesn't make even the slightest bit of sense. You cannot possibly reuse the same object to populate the array without copying the object each time you add it (which will give you new objects, just like creating a new `ListItem` each time does). If you use the same object each time, what exactly do you think happens when that object gets mutated? All reference to the object see the mutation! This is why you copy the object, or use a fresh object to begin with each time.

Comment: I see, using copy will still create a new object each time making that process virtually identical as far as memory allocation goes. So there is no advantage in using one over the other. At least no in my situation. I am confused on how to set my object to conform to NSCopying, but I should read up on that myself. Thanks so much for your explanations Kevin!

Comment: @Paul: I edited my answer to show an example of how to conform to `<NSCopying>`. Of course, in your case it may just be simpler to forget about copying and `alloc/init` a new instance each time.

Comment: I very much appreciate that!! ;]

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are using NSMutableArray, try chaining it to an NSArray.